# Declaring an interface with a key with reserved characters

Tags: typescript

In a library I use some functions might return objects like:

```
{
    wifiAddress: "abc...",
    3GAddress: "abc..."
}
```

I am creating a small declaration file for these but I am stuck here. How can I declare the second key (which starts with a number)?

```
interface AddressPair {
    wifiAddress: string,
    3GAddress: string // <-- ERROR here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised thanks to prior answers that this works:

```
interface AddressPair {
    wifiAddress: string;
    '3GAddress': string;
}
```

In this case `3GAddress` is special anyways so it cannot be accessed through the dot notation. since I need to use the brackets notation the compiler (autocomplete) cannot help me:

```
var a: AddressPair = { ... }
a.3GAddress; // With dot notation I would get autocomplete (for any other key) 
             // but in this case syntax it leads to an error.
a['3GAddress']; // Correct but no autocomplete :(
```

Comment: All this adds beyond Vasily's answer is additional information about a subsequent problem you encountered which there's no way someone could deduce from your original question. Are you sure you ought not to just accept Vasily's answer (to the question you asked)?

Comment: I think Vasily's answer is in plain javascript (At least that is what I understood). My question is about Typescript. This answer is in Typescript

Answer (score 3):

Is the syntax not this?

```
interface AddressPair {
    wifiAddress: string;
    3GAddress: string;
}
```

You need to end each declaration with a `;`.

Comment: Thanks, that was my bad. However that was another error. Declaring like you suggests still ends in errors.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows arbitrary string keys for hash objects. I'm not sure about Typescript, but you can try this:

```
{
    wifiAddress: "abc...",
    '3GAddress': "abc..."
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you made me realise the correct way of doing this :) I have added my answer based on yours :)